# Java Binary search with more the one result?

Tags: java, search, autocomplete, binary

I have a question to the binary search. I have an arraylist  where i use this to search the list for strings strting with an prefix:

```
    if(prefix.length()>1){
        prefixlow=prefix.toLowerCase();
        int n = Collections.binarySearch(words, prefixlow);
        if (n < 0 && -n <= words.size()) {
            String match = words.get(-n - 1);
            if (match.startsWith(prefixlow)) {
                // A completion is found
                completion = match.substring(0+prefix.length());

                keyboardwindow.jTextArea1.setText(prefix+completion);
            }
        }   
        else{keyboardwindow.jTextArea1.setText(prefix);}
    }
```

Now this is just finding me one result. The next step is to get all theword from the list starting with this prefix not just one. So the first question ist does this always find the first word starting with the prefix? Because as i think it gives you a random string just starting with the prefix...so any tipps how i get the starting postion and end position of strings starting with my prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary search over a `List<String>` will find the index of an exact occurrence of the prefix you are looking for. If your prefix appears multiple times in the `List` (not as a prefix of longer `String`s, but as the entire `String`), you'll get the index of one of those appearances (not necessarily the first).

However, it looks like you don't expect the prefix you are looking for to appear in the `List` (as an entire `String`), which is why you are expecting a negative index to be returned.

In that case, `binarySearch()` would return the negative value of the index in which your prefix would have appeared in the `List` according to the natural ordering of the elements.

Since the natural order of Strings is lexicographical order, the prefix would come before any longer `String`s that start with that prefix. Therefore you can simply iterate over the `List` starting at `-n - 1` and get all the `String`s starting with your prefix.

For example:

```
List<String> binSearch = Arrays.asList ("aaa","aab","aac","bba","bbb","bbbb","c");
System.out.println ("-n-1 = " +  (-Collections.binarySearch (binSearch, "bb")-1));
```

This prints:

```
-n-1 = 3
```

3 is the index at which the prefix "bb" would have been (had it been present in the `List`), but since it's not in the list, you know for such that all the `String`s starting with "bb" are located at indices >= 3.

Therefore your code can be modified by replacing the `if (match.startsWith(prefixlow))` condition with a loop:

```
if(prefix.length()>1) {
    prefixlow=prefix.toLowerCase();
    int n = Collections.binarySearch(words, prefixlow);
    if (n < 0 && -n <= words.size()) {
        String firstMatch = words.get(-n - 1);
        int i = -n - 1;
        String match = null;
        while (i < words.size() && (match = words.get(i)).startsWith(prefixlow)) {
            // A completion is found
            completion = match.substring(prefix.length());
            keyboardwindow.jTextArea1.setText(prefix+completion);
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        keyboardwindow.jTextArea1.setText(prefix);
    }
}
```

Comment: with this solution i get this error massage java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 24, Size: 24 Edit:oh ok its because my hole list starts with the prefix but so i need to stop the loop when he is in the last element

Answer (score 0):

You are correct here, you will get a random string with the searched prefix. But the array is sorted, so you can perform an interation in both directions from the found index, while(**yourPrefix** matches other string's prefix). That will get you the starting and ending indexes.